# KTDatatable серверная пагинация

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, datatable

Как в KTDatatable сделать серверную пагинацию. Даже вопрос в том, как при нажатии на номер страницы отправить запрос? Какой параметр отвечает за это.

В документации дается параметр

> toolbar.items.pagination.type: 'default'

Больше значений не дано.... Пробовал рыть - не нашел. Кто может подсказать? Уже две недели убил на это...

Comment: В смысле сделать пагинацию и какой параметр? Компонент наверняка готовый и в демо всё есть, события и всё остальное, вы просто кликаете по станице и он сам передает параметр и выдает с офсетом, просто всё нужно сделать по [мануалу](https://keenthemes.com/keen/?page=docs&section=datatable)

Comment: Я не работал с KTDatatable, но работал с Datatable и там всё работает само собой, нужно только в переменной указать что на стороне сервера всё выполняется. В официальной документации всё также присутствует, опишите поточней свой вопрос что конкретно происходит а что нет когда вы хоте то или иное действие совершить, потому что сейчас, мне допустим вообще ничего не понятно что у вас там творится!!!

Comment: @RifmaMan, сделал по мануалу, но сейчас отправляются з сервера все данные целеком, даже если параметр serverPaging:true. Просто на сервер отcылаются данные типа страница, количество элементом и т.д... Допустим я сделаю выборку как нужно и отправлю например только 10 элементов, но а как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на номер страницы в пагинации, отправлялся запрос. Сейчас не отправляется....

Comment: Вы не должны трогать скрипт отправки, все действия нужно делать на серверной стороне, а фронтенд не трогать, там должны работать базовые принципы пагинации, фильтрации и сортировки, опишите лучше что вы конкретно хотите сделать, может всё таки есть типовое решение, просто вы не с той стороны подошли к его решению так сказать...

Comment: Мол вот есть стандартная таблица, но мне нужно чтобы было еще вот это, я попробовал так, то, но как получить то-то, со скринами и кодом и тогда станет ясно, может вы вообще не туда полезли и велосипед собираете в компоненте

Comment: @RifmaMan да я его и не трогаю! Я не могу сделать отправку запроса по нажатию на номер страницы! НУ как еще сказать.... Таблица грузится только раз при загрузке страницы! А нужно каждый отправлять запрос при нажатии на пагинацию. Вот я и ищу параметр который отвечает за это

Comment: Вы понимаете что пагинация должна работать из коробки как и поиск и сортировка, ничего писать не нужно самостоятельно, [вот пример работы](https://keenthemes.com/keen/preview/demo1/components/keen-datatable/base/data-local.html). Datatable нужна для того, чтобы таблица аяксом обновлялась, в этом и суть её, а вы говорите что её основной функционал не работает и хотите его написать, вы видимо не правильно её подключили!!!

Comment: @RifmaMan то что вы кинули - пример не серверной пагинации